# massive amount of CLOSE_WAIT due nginx (lsof)

Tags: nginx, tcp

My VPS keeps hanging up every 5 days. I can see that the nginx worker processes are eating up my memory over time. I think this is due the massive amount of CLOSE_WAIT's open. When I type LSOF, I get tons and tons. A sample can be found below.

```
nginx      1934 www-data  170u     IPv4             476876        0t0        TCP something.com:www->141.101.98.116:10086 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  171u     IPv4            1162471        0t0        TCP something.com:www->cf-199-27-128-89.cloudflare.com:23774 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  172u     IPv4             567606        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.221.20:37267 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  173u     IPv4            2323097        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.245.14:23335 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  174u     IPv4            1344669        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.225.231:60467 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  175u     IPv4             743417        0t0        TCP something.com:www->197.234.243.4:59188 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  176u     IPv4            1798404        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.222.215:57796 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  177u     IPv4            1180153        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.238.45:17968 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  178u     IPv4             497718        0t0        TCP something.com:www->141.101.104.47:11815 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  179u     IPv4             567607        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.221.20:11240 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  180u     IPv4             432698        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.222.219:52570 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  181u     IPv4            3330260        0t0        TCP something.com:www->cf-173-245-50-213.cloudflare.com:15185 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  182u     IPv4             404397        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.229.221:17852 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  183u     IPv4             567609        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.221.20:31861 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  184u     IPv4             677137        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.225.154:22771 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  185u     IPv4             320850        0t0        TCP something.com:www->141.101.98.228:57247 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  186u     IPv4             566451        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.221.20:50783 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  187u     IPv4            1756167        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.237.32:18998 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  188u     IPv4             751612        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.219.73:26342 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  189u     IPv4             566453        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.221.20:32939 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  190u     IPv4            1973567        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.250.47:17339 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  191u     IPv4            1798441        0t0        TCP something.com:www->103.22.201.109:26477 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  192u     IPv4             829030        0t0        TCP something.com:www->cf-173-245-52-65.cloudflare.com:34624 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  193u     IPv4             168016        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.219.87:53679 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  194u     IPv4             751613        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.219.73:48552 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  195u     IPv4             744531        0t0        TCP something.com:www->197.234.243.4:55992 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  196u     IPv4             858578        0t0        TCP something.com:www->141.101.104.8:47353 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  197u     IPv4             744534        0t0        TCP something.com:www->197.234.243.4:23059 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  198u     IPv4             751615        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.219.73:43779 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  199u     IPv4             751616        0t0        TCP something.com:www->cf-173-245-56-246.cloudflare.com:30916 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  200u     IPv4            1189674        0t0        TCP something.com:www->173.245.54.17:27328 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  201u     IPv4            3184758        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.210.38:26233 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  202u     IPv4            1344668        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.225.231:39050 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  203u     IPv4            1181119        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.238.45:28510 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  204u     IPv4             285484        0t0        TCP something.com:www->cf-173-245-48-166.cloudflare.com:64434 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  205u     IPv4            1867742        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.215.134:64332 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  206u     IPv4            1946314        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.210.179:39163 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  207u     IPv4            1632128        0t0        TCP something.com:www->108.162.222.18:14036 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  208u     IPv4            1457453        0t0        TCP something.com:www->198.41.226.251:57972 (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx      1934 www-data  209u     IPv4            2123937        0t0        TCP something.com:www->141.101.98.114:11156 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Is there someone that can help me out with debugging and fixing this problem ? I think something is misconfigured and nginx keeps on waiting on certain connections. Is there a way to find what url's are called for these connections ?

EDIT: Nginx config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  6;
worker_rlimit_nofile 300000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  14000;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server_names_hash_max_size  812000;

    geoip_country  /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database
    geoip_city     /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat; # the city IP database

    log_format withhost '$host - $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

#    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log withhost;

#    set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
#    set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
#    set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
#    set_real_ip_from   2400:cb00::/32;
#    set_real_ip_from   2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from   69.164.223.55;
    set_real_ip_from   212.123.14.6;
    set_real_ip_from   192.168.255.17;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  30;

    client_body_timeout 20;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    send_timeout 5;

    server_tokens off;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

#    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#    include /nfs/vhosts/*;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;




server {
    server_name www.x.com;
    access_log off;
    error_log /srv/www/www.x.com/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/www.x.com/public_html/src/public;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Some version of IE 6 don't handle compression well on some mime-types, so just disable for them
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

    # Set a vary header so downstream proxies don't send cached gzipped content to IE6
    gzip_vary on;
    ## /Compression

    location ^~ /ads-management {
        auth_basic            "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file  /srv/www/www.x.com/public_html/.htpasswd;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    }

    location ~ ^/thumbnail/(.*)$ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$arg_code;
    }

    location / {
    #Don't use slash at end
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    if ($args ~* "/?q=(.*)") {
        rewrite ^ /search/q/$arg_q/? permanent;
    }


    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }


    location ~ .(php|phtml)$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/www.x.com/public_html/src/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

EDIT 2 TCP_MEM values:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem
47706   63610   95412
```

Thanks!

Comment: Every 5 Days, at the same moment ? Check the logs, post your nginx conf

Comment: Not at the same moment, but you can see the memory is running out over days. I posted the nginx conf etc, thanks! I Only can see `2015/04/15 06:46:44 [alert] 26304#0: 14000 worker_connections are not enough` in my logs

Comment: The error message means nignx could not accept more connections. For some reason, your clients decided to send a `FIN` flagged segment to tell the server that it is actively closing the connection while the server didn't answer with a `FIN` + `ACK` segment (if it did it would have switched to the `LAST_ACK` state). You can use `strace -fp <master_process_pid>` to check the syscalls related to what's happening. Maybe the server is hanging on a `send()`/`write()` call or something.